# Not able to set environment in the CSH shell using the .ksh file

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql, ksh, sql-loader

I am creating a script to extract the data from one DB and inserting the rows to another DB using the sql loader. I have developed all the scripts and compiled in the .ksh file and need to run the file but before I need to set the environment for using the tnsnames.ora file. Earlier, I had been manually giving the setenv command to set environment but I tried to set using the command in the .ksh file

```
set TNS_ADMIN = /abc/tnsnames.ora; export TNS_ADMIN
```

but the environment is not getting set.

I have started the shell using `#!/bin/ksh` but no avail.

```
SHELL = /bin/csh
```

Comment: In a Bourne shell derivative (Korn shell, Bash, etc), the `set` command, when invoked as shown, sets `$1` to `TNS_ADMIN`, `$2` to `=` and `$3` to `/abc/tnsnames.ora`.  The export exports an empty value for `TNS_ADMIN`.  You would need to use `TNS_ADMIN=/abc/tnsnames.ora; export TNS_ADMIN` or `export TNS_ADMIN=/abc/tnsnames.ora` to set the environment.  With C shell, you use `setenv` to set the environment.  In general, what works in C shell won't work in Bash or Korn shell, and vice versa.  The common syntax is limited — and doesn't include variable setting notations in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that syntax:

```
#!/bin/ksh
...
export TNS_ADMIN=/abc/tnsnames.ora
...
someScript.csh
...
```

Note that you cannot set `csh` environment variables from a sourced `ksh` script, if it is what you are trying to do. The only way to set `csh` variables when the script (or your interactive `csh` shell) is already running is by sourcing a file that uses the `csh` syntax, not the `ksh` one, eg:

```
setenv TNS_ADMIN /abc/tnsnames.ora
```

Finally, unless you have strong reasons to keep it, I would advise you to replace your login shell `csh` by a POSIX shell like `ksh` or `bash`. `csh` and `ksh` do not mix together.

Comment: I already tried that but not working. Is there any way I set the csh environment in the script, launch the command and exit the environment for the remaining commands.

Comment: It is unclear from your question and comment how you expect `csh` and `kshè to interact. Please update your question with a better description of what you want to do.

Comment: Why unclear? I have clearly mentioned that after coding the .ksh file, l am able to run export command but still the sql plus environment is not getting set unless I am manually executing the command setenv TNA_ADMIN /abc/tnsnames.ora

Comment: What is unclear is precisely how you expect a `ksh` script to interact with a `csh` script, i.e. the sequence of scripts you run and which ones call which other ones, and how. Environment variables can only be set from the current script or inherited from a parent script/command. If what I suggested is not working with you, please explain where and how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should write settings like `set TNS_ADMIN = /abc/tnsnames.ora` without spaces around the '='. When you have a file with such settings (let's call it setoracle.ksh), you must take care the file is sourced (read into the current environment, use a dot for that).
Now you have several approaches.

Start a ksh, source the settings and call your scripts

```
 ksh
 . setoracle.ksh
 extract_script
```

Start a script that will start the others.

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 [extract|insert|...]"
   exit 1
fi
. setoracle.ksh
case $1 in
   "extract") extract_script;;
   "insert") insert_script;;
   *) echo "$1 not supported";
esac
```

Source the settings in all your existing scripts.
Start insert_script and extract_script with

```
#!/bin/ksh
. setoracle.ksh
```